# How can I get a resource's schedule from google calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

We use google calendar to schedule our meetings.  We have set up each meeting room as a "resource" so that you can see availability and book a room by adding the resource to your meeting.

What I'd like to do is display today's schedule in for each room in each room.

I don't see a way to do that simply using google calendar, so I tried to do it programmatically with javascript through Google's API.  I could get the current user's schedule (see code below), but, not a resource's schedule.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get a single resource's schedule either visually as a day's schedule or programmatically so I can create a day's schedule?

```
  function listUpcomingEvents() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var events = resp.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')');
          var attendees = event.attendees;
          if (attendees.length > 0) {
            for (i=0; i<attendees.length; i++) {
              var attendee = attendees[i];
              if (attendee.resource) {
                appendPre('   RESOURCE: ' + attendee.displayName + ' (' + attendee.json + ')');
              } else {
                appendPre('   ' + attendee.displayName);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: How did you set up an availability time or date for your created resource?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find out the ID of your resource (it's an email address - resourceEmail - that you can for example see through the resource API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/). Once you have that, if the logged in account has read access to that resource's calendar, you can just replace calendarId in your query with the resourceEmail.

Comment: Ah... excellent!  Any idea how to get the ID of a given resource?  :)

Comment: The easiest way is the one through resource API which I tried to describe. You can also follow Mogsdad's explanation on how to get it from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see a way to do that simply using google calendar, ...

Using the same ID described in luc's answer, you can view a resource calendar in your browser.

A link would look like this, for example:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=CALENDAR-ID@resource.calendar.google.com&mode=WEEK&wkst=1&showCalendars=0
```

Note that you can control the view via URL parameters, so easy to keep a shortcut in a browser.

[image: screenshot]

**To view resource calendars within Google Calendar app:**

1. At the right of "Other Calendars", open the menu and select "Browse Interesting Calendars".
2. On the "Interesting Calendars" page, select "More", then "Resources for *domain*".
3. Find the resource you are interested in, and Preview the calendar.

To obtain the calendar ID, click on the "subscribe" button (lower right of preview), which will open a new window with a confirmation dialog. While this is visible, the calendar's ID can be copied from the URL bar, e.g. `https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=CALENDAR-ID@resource.calendar.google.com&blah...`